# How does mat.define-palette function work when setting text color?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Given the following palette:

```
$circle-q-warn-pallete: (
    50: #feedea,
    100: #fbd3ca,
    200: #f9b6a7,
    300: #f79984,
    400: #f58369,
    500: #f36d4f,
    600: #f16548,
    700: #ef5a3f,
    800: #ed5036,
    900: #ea3e26,
    A100: #ffffff,
    A200: #fff4f2,
    A400: #ffc6bf,
    A700: #ffafa6,
    contrast: (
        50: #000000,
        100: #000000,
        200: #000000,
        300: #000000,
        400: #ffffff,
        500: #ffffff,
        600: #000000,
        700: #000000,
        800: #ffffff,
        900: #ffffff,
        A100: #000000,
        A200: #000000,
        A400: #ffffff,
        A700: #000000,
    ),
);
```

When defining warn color palette with the following function:

```
$circle-q-warn: mat.define-palette($circle-q-warn-pallete, $default: 500, $lighter: 100, $darker: 700, $text: 600);
```

and understanding that the signature for `define-palette` is as follow:

```
@function define-palette($base-palette, $default: 500, $lighter: 100, $darker: 700,
  $text: $default)
```

Setting $text parameter to 600 (which maps to contrast: white color) `$text: 600` why is my text on the page not changing to white?